# Portainer - how to specify SSL in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I'm trying to deploy an instance of Portainer to a docker swarm.  I'm not sure how to set the correct flag to enable SSL.

From the docs:

```
$ docker run -d -p 443:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v ~/local-certs:/certs -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer --ssl --sslcert /certs/portainer.crt --sslkey /certs/portainer.key
```

https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html

But how do you translate that into a docker compose yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://composerize.com/ can help to translate your `docker` command into a `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: composerize doesn't translate --ssl --sslcert and --sslkey flags

Answer (score 18):

Possibly I'm a bit late to the party, but it looks what you have to use Portainer's flags to enable ssl for your Portainer (as said in [documentation](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#secure-portainer-using-ssl)) and [composerize.com](https://composerize.com) lost that part somewhere, so you should add this to your compose:

```
command:
  --sslcert /certs/portainer.crt
  --sslkey /certs/portainer.key
```

or for full compose file:

```
version: 3
services:
    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        container_name: portainer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '443:9443' # CONTAINER PORT MUST BE 9443 and not 9000 when using SSL
        volumes:
            - '~/local-certs:/certs'
            - 'portainer_data:/data'
        command:
            --sslcert /certs/portainer.crt
            --sslkey /certs/portainer.key
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [Portainer documentation](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#secure-portainer-using-ssl):

> By default, Portainer’s web interface and API is exposed over HTTP.
>   This is not secured, it’s recommended to enable SSL in a production
>   environment.
>
> To do so, you can use the following flags --ssl, --sslcert and
>   --sslkey:
>
> `$ docker run -d -p 443:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v
>       ~/local-certs:/certs -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer --ssl
>       --sslcert /certs/portainer.crt --sslkey /certs/portainer.key`
>
> You can use the following commands to generate the required files:
>
> `$ openssl genrsa -out portainer.key 2048 
>   $ openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out portainer.key 
>   $ openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key portainer.key -out portainer.crt -days 3650`
>
> Note that Certbot could be used as well to generate a certificate and a key.

As [Rubin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922925/2144342), you can use https://composerize.com/ to generate a `docker-compose.yml` from `docker` command.

So, your docker-compose file should be something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        container_name: portainer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '443:9000'
        volumes:
            - '~/local-certs:/certs'
            - 'portainer_data:/data'
        command:
            --ssl
            --sslcert /certs/portainer.crt
            --sslkey /certs/portainer.key
volumes:
    portainer_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
version: '3'
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    volumes:
    - "/local-certs:/certs"
    - "portainer_data:/data"
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    container_name: portainer
    command:
    - --ssl
    - --sslcert
    - /certs/wildcard.crt
    - --sslkey 
    - /certs/wildcard.key
```